# Having issue with ng-bind and datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, datepicker

Data field is StartDate. Data is retrieved from server via ajax call in Json format. StartDate comes as JSON date /Date(1453356000000)/.

A textbox is bound using ng-bind as seen below:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="di.StartDate | JSONdate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'" required placeholder="dd-MMM-yyyy" data-dateformat="dd-M-yy" datepicker />
```

Date is displayed as `21-Jan-2016` as expected.

When I click the textbox to change the date, datepicker pops up and I select a new date.

Now the problem is in the JSON object (di) an new attribute/property is created along with the original `StartDate` attribute/property.

```
StartDate : /Date(1453356000000)/
StartDate | JSONdate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' : '12-Jan-2016'
```

[Screenshot#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxiaJ.png)

Comment: are you sure it creates a new property with same name? Check it carefully both property names might be different, either spelling mistake or difference in cases like startDate and StartDate.

Comment: please refer to the screenshot (http://i.stack.imgur.com/uxiaJ.png), though it is from another example, but the same issue. In this case it is Date.